# Potentially stupid conjecture

Tags: complex-numbers

My dormmate and I were talking about the fourth dimension and then thought about it and wondered if the complex number line could be the fourth dimension. Is this a thing, or are there any conjectures in math regarding the fourth dimension?

Comment: The complex numbers do not have an ordering (unless you are comparing real numbers, which are of course technically complex numbers as well), so I'm not sure what you mean by complex number line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misinterpreting the complex numbers. They don't form a line in the usual sense of the word, in fact they form a plane. Every complex number is of the form `a+bi`, where both a and b are real numbers. So the set of complex numbers is two dimensional in the usual sense of the term.

If you are saying something different, can you be more specific as to what you mean? What fact about complex numbers are you saying is four dimensional?

Also, there are many conjectures in mathematics about the fourth dimension. There is really nothing different about the fourth dimension other than our inability to visualize it. If we were four dimensional beings in a four dimensional world, the fourth dimension would make just as much sense as the lower dimensions.

Comment: Exactly which conjectures about the fourth dimension do you mean?  There are many 4-dimensional objects that are very ordinary from a mathematical perspective.  Our ability to visualize something in mathematics is hardly every needed to prove mathematical principles.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about multiple dimensions (beyond 3) is a very common thing in many areas of mathematics.  Linear algebra deals with vector spaces of any number of dimensions $n = 1,2,3,4, \ldots$.  In mathematics we're interested also in talking about various canonical sets.  Of typical interest are the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, $n$-dimensional Euclidean (real space) $\mathbb{R}^n$, and their complex analogs $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{C}^n$.  You can think of a four-dimensional space mathematically in different ways.  For instance, the spaces $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{C}^2$ are algebraically, and topologically equivalent.  When you say whether or not the complex number line makes up the fourth dimension, you have to talk about what space this is in.  If you're wondering if there is a fourth dimension in terms of physical reality, then in physics time is generally considered to be a fourth dimension, but I wouldn't try to visualize any weird light-cone stuff and mistake that for reality.  Normally in mathematics and physics we try to characterize systems by how many independent coordinates are needed, or "degrees of freedom", and this can vary from situation to situation.  A point particle can be fully characterized in six dimensions (3 spatial dimensions for location, and 3 velocity/momentum dimensions), and a rigid body would in fact need 12 dimensions (3 spatial for the center of mass, 3 for the velocity/momentum of the center of mass, 3 for orientation, and 3 more for angular velocity/momentum).

To sum up, from a mathematical perspective I would recommend thinking about dimensions as reflecting the number of independent degrees of freedom, or coordinate parameters are needed, to characterize a system.  An interesting thing to think about though is what geometric structure all of those coordinates look like when they're assembled together.  If the coordinates behave in a "linear" fashion when assembled then they combine to make a Euclidean space.  It's when they don't form a linear space is when things get really interesting!